# How to receive the video stream of a Tello drone using Processing and UDP

Tags: java, udp, video-streaming, processing, dji-sdk

I am trying to receive the video stream of my Tello drone using Processing as stated in its [SDK documentation](https://github.com/grofattila/dji-tello/blob/master/Tello%20SDK%20Documentation%20EN_1.3_1122.pdf):
[image]

To receive the video stream via UDP I have tried to use [a script by The Coding Train](https://github.com/shiffman/Processing-UDP-Video-Streaming/blob/master/VideoReceiver/VideoReceiver.pde):

```java
import java.awt.image.*; 
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


// Port we are receiving.
int port = 11111; 
DatagramSocket ds; 
// A byte array to read into (max size of 65536, could be smaller)
byte[] buffer = new byte[65536]; 

PImage video;

void setup() {
  size(400,300);
  try {
    ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
  } catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  video = createImage(320,240,RGB);
}

 void draw() {
  // checkForImage() is blocking, stay tuned for threaded example!
  checkForImage();

  // Draw the image
  background(0);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(video,width/2,height/2);
}

void checkForImage() {
  DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length); 
  try {
    ds.receive(p);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  byte[] data = p.getData();

  println("Received datagram with " + data.length + " bytes." );

  // Read incoming data into a ByteArrayInputStream
  ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( data );

  // We need to unpack JPG and put it in the PImage video
  video.loadPixels();
  try {
    // Make a BufferedImage out of the incoming bytes
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bais);
    // Put the pixels into the video PImage
    img.getRGB(0, 0, video.width, video.height, video.pixels, 0, video.width);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  // Update the PImage pixels
  video.updatePixels();
}
```

The only thing I changed in the script is the variable `port` as the SDK documentation (see above) specifies, that it should be `11111`.

When I run the script (after successfully sending `command` and `streamon` to the drone), I get the message `Received datagram with 65536 bytes.` and a Null Pointer Exception. I've found out, that the Null Pointer Exception is shown, because the following line of code returns `null`:

```java
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bais);
```

So in the end, my question is, why this line of code or more specifically `ImageIO.read(bais)` returns `null`. However, the script works correctly, if you use it combined with the [Video Sender script of the Coding Train](https://github.com/shiffman/Processing-UDP-Video-Streaming/blob/master/VideoSender/VideoSender.pde). So, what's the problem here?

Comment: u sure ImageIO.read can decode H.264 stream? As far as I know. dji system always need H.264 stream over UDP port for data reduction.  On the receiving end, you can use ffshow to verify the incomming stream on PC. if can see the image. that means the imageIO can not decode the stream

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai Thank you for your answer! So, do you have an idea how to decode the H.264 stream using processing/java?

Comment: I did not find any prpper API and data reference for Processing Codec.  Guess whey only plan for an image or webcam(atmost) like basic IO.  One way to walk around is to use ffmpeg to convert incomming udp to a local virtual webcam port. then use processing to read this webcam.  If processing cant support webcam, then use ffmpeg to save as jpeg file and reads it in processing

Comment: first try with ffshow to confirm everything else is ok

Comment: Do you mean ffdshow?

Comment: sry not ffshow.  ffplay -f h264 -i udp://192.168.1.45:23003 . this is how i test DJI PSDK. change the ip and port to tellos

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai I've successfully tried out ffplay and can now see the drone's live video stream on my Mac. So the next step is to set up a virtual webcam port. I don't have figured out yet, how I can do this using ffmpeg. Can you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196076/discussion-between-paul-and-dr-yuan-shenghai).